# Can't create new project in Android Studio on Mac OS

Tags: android, android-studio

I downloaded the android studio version 0.1 for Mac, and installed it into Applications. When I open this new tool and try to create a new project, it report an error like this:

> Your Android SDK is out of date or is missing templates. Please ensure you are using SDK version 22 or later.

Comment: Update/install the sdk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can download the sdk from here : http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

And then go into Configure → Project Defaults → Project Structure → Project

Add new SDK and referencing to the SDK Folder that you have download and extract before and then click apply and ok.

I have tried it before, and going well.

Answer (score 2):

First, update to v22.  Then go into Configure → Project Defaults → Project Structure → Project

Add a new SDK, referencing wherever you installed it.  Fiddle with stuff on these screens until nothing is red.  Go to SDK.  Again, you want no red.

There are taken from Windows, may be slightly different on Mac

Comment: Now if you can figure out how to get it to save to any folder other than the default, that'd be great.  I'm sick of Eclipse bugs, but this is getting to the point where better the devil I know.

Comment: Excellent, solved it for me. 
By the way, the SDK comes with the Downloaded Android Studio. 
Windows: \Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\
Mac: /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/sdk/