# Android studio is not working on windows 7

Tags: android, java, java-7, android-studio

I downloaded `android-studio-bundle-130.677228-windows` and installed it on my computer. But when I tried to launch the android studio, nothing happening there...Its not launching, no errors. I also tried to run it as administrator, but not working. What is the actual problem there? Is anyone experiencing the same problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16578471/cant-create-new-project-in-android-studio-on-mac-os?rq=1 check this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-install-on-windows-7-fails-no-jdk-found

Comment: For Windows 7 all Android Studio versions since 2022 don't work with symptoms like Java SDK, JAVA_HOME, etc  Don't waste the time - downgrade the version to Android Studio 4.0.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you have to set up the environment variables in windows 7 , 
for instance:

```
JDK_HOME -> c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\
```

you may go **[How to set up JDK_HOME Environment Variable](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Setting+the+JAVA_HOME+Variable+in+Windows)** In case, you do not know how to set this variable.

Hope this will Help.

Comment: It worked, but the main problem now is telling that I don't have te lastest SDK installed, so?

Comment: @rokimoki: For this you should go to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869929/update-android-sdk-tool-to-22-0-0latest-version-from-21-1-0/14871487#14871487

Comment: @BhaveshPatadiya I updated JDK_HOME. But no change. Still same problem. I am using JDK 6, Should i install latest version ?

Answer (score 8):

Ok, simple as this:

1. Find you JDK folder path (usually in this format: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0) and copy it.
2. On windows, click on start --> type "Path" and open Environment Variables window.
3. In System variables section --> click New
4. Variable name: JDK_HOME
5. Variable value: JDK Folder path from part 1.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you follow google plus more often for latest Android happenings. There are already plenty of discussion in their [community](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/105153134372062985968) . Make sure you set JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME appropriately, or look into [this](http://www.ootpapps.com/2013/05/android-studio-wont-open-how-to-fix-android-studio/).

Comment: If this is not working for you, also add "ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK" to the same location as java home.