# Cannot create a new project in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

- So I downloaded Android Studio setup.
- Added `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.
- Installed the studio and it ran properly after quite an experimentation.
- Unable to create new project coz of this error --
  `Your Android SDK is out of date or is missing templates. Please ensure you are using SDK version 22 or later.`
- Changed the project structure settings. [Similar to this on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16578471/cant-create-new-project-in-android-studio-on-mac-os). Still can't create coz of the same error.
- Checked SDK manager. It says I already have version 22 of `SDK tools`. Re-installed it. Still unable to create a new project.

What should I do to make it work?

**NOTE** - I don't have eclipse or anything of android installed previously in the system.

Answer (score 3):

Delete the **~/.AndroidStudioPreview** config and try again.